# Open another terminal to execute a command with ongoing aoutput in bash script - how continue the bash script?

Tags: bash, terminal, process, konsole

I have a bash script which starts two local blockchain nodes instead of saving the output into a log file, i want to open a terminal for printing it continuously on the terminal:

I tried

> `konsole --noclose -e blockchain start`

but then the bash script does not continue to the next command in the script.

Any ideas how to keep the script running while opening 2 terminals with ongoing output?

Comment: Add `&` to the end to background it and continue.

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Wrote this up as a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by putting an `&` on the end of the command:

```
konsole --noclose -e blockchain start &
```

This flags to the shell that it should execute the command in the background in a subshell. The effect is that the shell doesn't wait for the command to finish, and continues immediately.